# read in a string s output a string consisting of only the even-positioned characters from s

Tags: python, python-2.7

Read in a string `s`, output a string consisting of only the even-positioned characters from `s`.
I can print like print `s[0] + s[2]` but is there any general solution so print even position characters of a 100 word string etc

```
s =raw_input()
i = 0
while i < len(s):
    print s[0] + s[2] + s[4]
    i = i + 1
```

Comment: This is a little broad. And, frankly, SO is no "instructions in, code out"-machine.

Comment: @palsch it wasn't but in fact it is :(

Comment: What about ``s[::2]``?

Answer (score 2):

Looping is not necessary for this task.  In python you can use slices on strings, skipping with a stepsize of 2.

```
print s[::2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
s = raw_input()
for i in xrange(0, len(s), 2):
  print s[i]
```

Or, if you like list comprehensions:

```
''.join([s[i] for i in xrange(0, len(s), 2)])
```

The list slicing answer is also particularly nice.

Answer (score 0):

A common way to find whether or not a number is even is by using the modulo operator. For example 1%2 = 1, thus one isn't even. 4%2 = 0, thus 4 is even.

Now, to apply this more generally, inside your loop you want to check if i is even by comparing the result of i%2 with 0. This will tell you whether or not to print that character from the string.

Comment: 0a1b2c3d4e5
--

-- output i want is
012345

Comment: if i%2 == 0: print s[i]

Comment: it works but prints 0 one line and 1 on anoter etc how i print all on same line?

Comment: If you want to print it all on the same line, you should just build a string and then print it once the original string has been iterated over. ex:     evenChars = "", evenChars += s[i]

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution: group the characters in the string two by two and only pick the even ones

```
from itertools import zip_longest

s = '0a1b2c3d4e5'
es = ''.join(even for even, _ in zip_longest(*[iter(s)]*2))
print(es)
```

produces

```
012345
```

In case we looked for the odd ones we could use the plain `zip`

```
es = ''.join(odd for _, odd in zip(*[iter(s)]*2))
```

producing

```
abcde
```